# Convert 2d array to 1d array by summing row values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, flatten

I have associative 2d array:

```
[
    'food' => [3, 4, 1],
    'liquor'=> [4, 5, 0],
    'beer' => [5, 6, 0],
]
```

I need to use array_sum on each subarray so result would be:

```
[
    'food' => 8,
    'liquor' => 9,
    'beer' => 11,
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = array_map('array_sum', $your_array);
```

Example: http://ideone.com/LqTAV